# Upload in Firebase Storage and fetch link to add it in Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, async-await

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Storage in this application, the goal is to upload in Firebase Storage the images in the `pictures` array, and then get the link of the Firebase Storage to that image and add it in the object which will be pushed in `imagesUriArray` and added to Realtime Database. The problem is that when I press `addItem` it successfully update the id, but the `images` parameter remains empty. And in fact, `imagesUriArray` remains empty unless I refresh the screen.

```
 export default function NewItem({ route, navigation }) {

    const [pictures, setPictures] = useState([]);
    const [imagesUriArray, setImageUriArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={addItem}>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>ADD ITEM</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    })
    

    const addItem = async () => {

            uploadImages()

            const changes = ref(db, path)
                get(changes).then(async (snapshot) => {
                    if (snapshot.val().data !== undefined) {
                        const fetchedArray = snapshot.val().data

                        let array = fetchedArray;

                        let object = {
                            "id": `${Math.random()}`,
                            "images": imagesUriArray,
                        }

                        array.push(object)
                    
                        update(changes, {
                            data: array
                        })
                    
                    }
                })
        }
    }

    const uploadImages = () => {

        const metadata = {
            contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        };


        pictures.forEach( async (obj) => {
            const id = obj.id
            const uri = obj.uri

            const response = await fetch(uri);
            const blob = await response.blob();
            var ref = storageUpload(storage, path)
            await uploadBytes(ref, blob, metadata)

            await getDownloadURL(ref)
            .then((metadata) => {
                let array = imagesUriArray
                    
                let object = {
                    "id": id,
                    "uri": metadata
                }

                array.push(object)
                setImageUriArray(array)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
        })
    }

  return(
     ..............
  )
}
```

Comment: Well, I think I see an additional issue. My answer below addresses the `imagesUriArray` being empty, but I just noticed you are calling `uploadImages` and appear to be expecting to see the updated `imagesUriArray` state in the rest of the `addItem` callback. Is this correct and still an issue after addressing the state updates in `uploadImages`?

Comment: Yes it is, actually, the app crashes when I execute the code

Comment: @DrewReese Basically what I'm trying to do is let the user pick some images and store them in the `pictures` state, then when the user wants to add the new item in the database, I use `addItem` and `uploadImage`, which gets each image, upload it to Storage and retrieve the link, save them in the state `imagesUriArray`  and save the state with links in Realtime Database

Comment: Yeah, ok, I think I see more of what you are trying to accomplish now. `uploadImages` isn't an `async` function and executes synchronously. `addItem` isn't waiting for anything it does to complete *prior* starting its own asynchronous code. On top of that, the `imagesUriArray` it references likely won't be the updated state. I'll see about updating my answer a bit.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

This appears to be a state mutation in the `uploadImages` callback. A reference to the `imagesUriArray` state is cached locally, mutated (*i.e. direct push into array*), and then the same reference is saved back into state. This doesn't trigger react to rerender with any updated state value.

```
const uploadImages = () => {
  ...
  
  pictures.forEach( async (obj) => {
    const id = obj.id
    const uri = obj.uri

    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    var ref = storageUpload(storage, path)
    await uploadBytes(ref, blob, metadata)

    await getDownloadURL(ref)
      .then((metadata) => {
        let array = imagesUriArray // <-- reference to state
                    
        let object = {
          "id": id,
          "uri": metadata
        }

        array.push(object)         // <-- state mutation
        setImageUriArray(array)    // <-- same state reference
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  })
};
```

## Solution

Use a functional state update to update from the previous state. Create a shallow copy of the previous state and append the new data.

```
const uploadImages = () => {
  ...
  
  pictures.forEach( async (obj) => {
    const { id, uri } = obj;

    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const ref = storageUpload(storage, path);
    await uploadBytes(ref, blob, metadata);

    await getDownloadURL(ref)
      .then((uri) => {
        setImageUriArray(imagesUriArray => [
          ... imagesUriArray, // <-- shallow copy
          { id, uri },        // <-- append new object
        ]);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  })
};
```

### Update

`uploadImages` needs to return a Promise so that `addItem` can wait for it to complete its asynchronous code. `addItem` also needs to access the updated `imagesUriArray` that `uploadImages` updates.

Map the `pictures` array to an array of Promises (*i.e. an `async` `fetchImageUri` function*) that eventually returns the object with `id` and new `uri` properties.

```
const uploadImages = () => {
  ...

  const fetchImageUri = async ({ id, uri }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const ref = storageUpload(storage, path);
      await uploadBytes(ref, blob, metadata);

      const newUri = await getDownloadURL(ref);
      return { id, uri: newUrl };
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return Promise.all(pictures.map(fetchImageUri));
};
```

Update `addItem` to wait for the resolved array of Promises that contain the uploaded image data. Enqueue the `imagesUriArray` state update here, then continue the rest of the function referencing the returned `uploadedImages` array from `uploadImages`.

```
const addItem = async () => {
  const uploadedImages = await uploadImages();
  setImageUriArray(imagesUriArray => [
    ...imagesUriArray, // <-- shallow copy
    ...uploadedImages, // <-- append new objects
  ]);

  const changes = ref(db, path);
  get(changes).then(async (snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.val().data !== undefined) {
      const fetchedArray = snapshot.val().data;
      const object = {
        id: `${Math.random()}`,
        images: uploadedImages,
      };

      update(changes, { data: [...fetchedArray, object] });     
    }
  });
}
```